# SQL separate table for relationship pros & cons

Tags: sql, database-design, schema

I am working on database design so want to understand the pros & cons of having a separate table only for relationship.

It should be like:

1. Customer [Customer Detail] (CustomerID AS PK)
2. Address  [Address Detail] (AddressID as PK)
3. CustomerAddress  [CustomerID FK, AddressID FK]

Or

1. Customer [Customer Detail] (CustomerID AS PK)
2. Address  [Address Detail, CustomerID FK]

A customer can have more than one address.

What are the advantage and disadvantage?

Comment: If each customer will have unique address then you can have all information in single table

Comment: A customer can have many addresses, thanks for pointing

Comment: Also can a single address be shared by two customer ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a reasonable question.

Basically, it boils down to a single question:  "Do you want two identical addresses to always have the same key or not?".

In the first version, the "Address Detail" can be unique across the database.  So, two room-mates could have the same `AddressId`.  When the Smith's move out and the Jones' move in, they could have the same `AddressId`.

In the second version, each person would have one or more address records.  However, the details for a given address could be repeated.

Which is better depends on your application.  Often, the first method is preferable when you are contacting people at the address, because "de-duplication" is built into the data model

Comment: +1 Nice concise answer.  I always think of geography as a dimension.  123 Main Street is always 123 Main Street as Jan 23 is always Jan23.